# For a cyclotomic polynomial with p = 5, prove that $G(Q(\alpha)/Q)$ is isomorphic to $C_4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

I'm currently self-studying and would like to understand automorphisms in relation to splitting fields. Could someone please help me with this question?

I'm trying explicitly to write down each automorphism of the splitting field $Q(\alpha)$ (with $Q$ fixed) in terms of a single generator for the group.

I believe that the automorphism - $\psi_{\alpha, \alpha^2}$ will be of use here. $\alpha$ is a root.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extension is Galois, since all the primitive roots of unity are roots of this cyclotomic polynomial (  where I assume $\alpha$ a primitive fifth root of unity)Any automorphism must map a primtive root of unity to another primitive roots of unity, so at most we have 4 automorphisms. We exactly have 4 automorphisms since the extension is Galois of degree 4. Hence we have a natural map rom $(\mathbf{Z}/5\mathbf{Z})^{*} \to Gal(Q(\alpha)/Q)$, given by a (mod 5) to $\sigma_{a}$ where $\sigma_{a} (\alpha)=\alpha^{a}$. This map is injective since the idendtity map is only given by $a=1$! Since the two groups have equal size, they are isomorphic. Now since 5 is prime, $(\mathbf{Z}/5\mathbf{Z})^{*}$ is cyclic of order 5-1=4.

Comment: Thank you! I shall look over this.